# I cannot build deb package

Tags: linux, deb

I want to build package which have

```
/package/debtest/
/package/debtest/bin
/package/debtest/bin/E01.bin
/package/debtest/bin/E02.bin
/package/debtest/bin/E03.bin``
/package/debtest/log
/package/debtest/mon
```

I want to install to directory /opt/debtest/

This is my rule file

```
 #!/usr/bin/make -f
    # -*- makefile -*-
    # Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
    # This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
    # As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
    # dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
    # This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.


install:

install -d /opt/debtest/
install -d /opt/debtest/bin
install -d /opt/debtest/log
install -d /opt/debtest//mon


****# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.**
****#export DH_VERBOSE=1******

%:
    dh $@
```

when use dpkg-buildpackage command it view this

dpkg-source --before-build debtest-1.0
debian/rules clean
debian/rules:11: *** missing separator.  Stop.

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think there is a sane way to have `dpkg` put your stuff in `/opt`. It has very good reasons to install in `/usr` and I cannot imagine a scenario in which the benefits of coercing it could have the shadow of a chance to outweigh the drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid Makefile syntax. Each target should contain a number if indented commands. The indentation must begin with a literal tab character.

What you are apparently trying to accomplish is better done with a `debian/dirs` file, though. You don't put regular Makefile targets in a `debian/rules` file anyway.

Comment: I don't want to makefile this package make for copy file into destination directory only.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, my editor as autochangind tab to two blankspaces.